# what is the jvm byte[] instance charset

Tags: java, jvm, jvisualvm

I run application using `idea` and dump heap useing `jvisualvm`. a byte[] instance looks like `5, 0, -110, 104, 6, 9, 1, 2, -112, -128, -127, 0, 9, -110, 100, 2, 5, 84, 114, 101, 101, 115, 10, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 97, 112, 105, 10, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 114, 101, 102, 108, 101, 99, 116, 10, 1, 7, 1, 5, 115, 99, 97, 108, 97, 3, 0, 19, 2, 0, 10, 16, 2, 11, 12, 13, 1...`
[image: too many byte[]]
[image]
I want to see byte message , but the result turns Garbled, what should i do?

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());  // UTF-8
byte[] bytes = {5, 0, -110, 104, 6, 9, 1, 2, -112...};
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's actually String data?

Comment: There are some ascii strings hidden in the data you’ve posted (four, to be precise), each of them being preceded by its length as a single byte, but there are also other data in between. Seems to be Scala reflection information.

Comment: @AndyTurner  maybe i choose wrong one.  another example  `123, 34, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 34, 58, 123, 34, 95, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 100, 100, 55, 97, 55, 50, 97, 56, 99, 55, 101, 50, 56, 50, 55, 57, 97, 55, 55, 54, 97, 51, 55, 52, 97, 48, 57, 50, 57, 102, 57, 101, 34, 125, 125, 10, 123, 34, 111, 118, 101, 114, 118`   It is a kafka message

Comment: @Holger  I can decode  ascii byte[], but i do not know how to deal with others 
  `String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
        String[] list = str.split(",");
        for (String s : list) {
            byte b = Byte.valueOf(s.trim());
            char c = (char) b;
            System.out.print(c);
            i++;} `

Comment: I’m not sure what you are trying to do. If the byte array truly is the backing array of a `String` instance, you only need do expand the `<references>` tree node in the heap dump analyzer and click on the referencing string object, to see the content as decoded string. Or browse the string instances in the first place. If the byte array is not an actual string, it can be anything and we don’t know how to decode it. By the way, the code of your comment can be simplified to `for(String s: str.split(",\\s*")) System.out.printf("%c", Byte.valueOf(s));`